# Regex - Search for text which doesn't contain either of two substrings after another substring match

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm looking to create a regex expression that can search for the following:

- style={
- style={\n
- style: {
- style: {\n

Where those matches without a newline can contain more text after the match, e.g:

- style={this is ok}
- style={ this is also ok }
- style: {this is fine}
- style: { this is also fine }

But can't contain the following:

- style={/*
- style={ /*
- style: {/*
- style: { /*

i.e. The substring `/*` and  `/*` are not acceptable after the opening brace.

Currently I have `style[=:][ \n]{0,1}\{` but I'm not sure how to finalize the last part.

*Note: I'm implementing this expression as a search parameter in VSCode (PCRE2 I believe)*

Comment: in 2 steps? replace('/*.+?*/', '') then search ?

Comment: Try `\bstyle[:=]\s*\{(?!.*/\*)\n?`, see https://regex101.com/r/U88J8h/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\bstyle[:=]\s*\{(?!.*/\*)\n?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U88J8h/1). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `style` - a string
- `[:=]` - `:` or `=` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\{` - a `{` char
- `(?!.*/\*)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there cannot be any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with `/*` substring
- `\n?` - an optional line break.

Comment: One slight mistake, the forward slash needs to be escaped as follows: `\bstyle[:=]\s*\{(?!.*\/\*)\n?` (PCRE2)

Comment: @ShaneCallanan There is no mistake here. `/` is not any special regex metacharacter and need no escaping.

Comment: See here: https://regex101.com/r/CvK1RR/1 (Note: Using PCRE2, not PCRE)

Comment: @ShaneCallanan Please learn to use online regex testers. See [what I mean](https://regex101.com/r/z9yTo1/1). Besides,in Visual Studio Code, you are not using any regex delimiters, so you just can't use `/` to delimit the *regex pattern*.

Comment: ... and there is no need to escape forward slashes in the find and replace dialog.

Comment: Ok, thanks Wiktor. Btw you're right, I need to look into regex more. I saw you used a different delimiter in your example.